# Save file to SharePoint online from node using username and password

Tags: node.js, authentication, sharepoint

I'm trying to save a file from a node process to a Sharepoint online directory using the username and password of an account created in Azure AD.

The url for the SharePoint site is https://[tenant_name].sharepoint.com/sites/datatarget and specifically a nested folder in 'Shared Documents' like /directoryA/directoryB. The user has been given permissions only on that folder in SharePoint. I am able to login to SharePoint using the account and create files in that directory so the user does have the proper permissions.

Is that possible?

I'd like to authenticate using the username and password and not a Sharepoint add-in only because from what I can tell you can't get permissions specific enough with add-ins. It seems to be very broad permissions with add-ins. Please correct me if that is wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using the PnPjs library but authentication would not be done via the accounts username and password. You will have to register an app on Azure and grant that account permissions to read and write on SharePoint.

You can see details on how to setup the authentication via the link: https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/authentication/server-nodejs/#call-sharepoint-

You can add files using the steps described in the link:
https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/files/#adding-a-file-using-nodejs-streams